# Loop through columns and filter out values based on quantiles for each column

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, quantile

Starting with a dataframe that consists of different sites and a number of statistics...

```
test_df <- data.frame(site = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"), stat1 = c(0.44, 11, 0.45, 0, 5, 2, 2.3, 1.8, -3, 0), stat2 = c(10, 9, 10.1, 8, 7, 8.2, 8, 9.5, 9.6, 8), stat3 = c(0, 0.2, 0, 0.1, 0.15, 0.12, 1, -1, 0.15, 0.11))

# site  stat1  stat2  stat3  
#   A    0.44    10     0     
#   B    11      9     0.2    
#   C    0.45    10.1    0
#   D    0       8     0.1
#   E    5       7     0.15
#   F    2       8.2   0.12
#   G    2.3     8      1
#   H    1.8     9.5   -1
#   I    -3      9.6   0.15
#   J    0       8     0.11
```

I would like to loop through each of the statistics and output a single dataframe where the only values that are present for each stat are those that are above the 75th percentile or below the 25th percentile value for that specific column, which would look something like this...

```
# site  stat1  stat2  stat3  
#   A    NA      10     0     
#   B    11      NA     0.2    
#   C    NA      10.1   0
#   D    0       NA     NA
#   E    5       7      NA
#   F    NA      NA     0.12
#   G    2.3     NA     1
#   H    NA      NA     -1
#   I    -3      9.6    NA
#   J    0       NA     NA
```

Here is my approach so far...

```
# I know I can filter out values for one stat at a time by doing the following...

stat1_df <- test_df %>% filter(stat1 > quantile(stat1, 0.75) | (stat1 < quantile(stat1, 0.25))) %>% select(site, stat1)

stat1_df

#   site stat1
#   B   11.0
#   D   0.0
#   E   5.0
#   G   2.3
#   I   -3.0
#   J   0.0
```

But I'm struggling to make it so I can automate/loop through the stat columns and create my desired final dataframe with all of the columns. I would appreciate any ideas. The actual files I'll be working with have 100+ stats, so I'm really focused on automating as much as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply could use `lapply`.

```
test_df[-1] <- lapply(test_df[-1], function(x) {
  q <- quantile(x, prob=c(.25, .75))
  x[!(x < q[1] | x > q[2])] <- NA
  x
})
test_df
#    site stat1 stat2 stat3
# 1     A    NA  10.0   0.0
# 2     B  11.0    NA   0.2
# 3     C    NA  10.1   0.0
# 4     D   0.0    NA    NA
# 5     E   5.0   7.0    NA
# 6     F    NA    NA    NA
# 7     G   2.3    NA   1.0
# 8     H    NA    NA  -1.0
# 9     I  -3.0   9.6    NA
# 10    J   0.0    NA    NA
```